# How to open illusory walls with messages in front of it?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There's so many messages that hint illusory walls, but when I press X (PS3) in front of it, I ended up opening the message because it's so close to the wall. is there a way around?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there is actually an illusory wall, it will take precedence over reading the message when you hit the interact button. Many of these "illusory wall" messages are in fact fake and attempts at trolling. So, if you find an illusory wall message, try getting close and interacting. If it doesn't work, then the message was a lie.

Comment: Like the messages that tell you to try a torch near Agdayne. And there are the helpful messages that attempt to be vulgar: "Destroy but hole".

Comment: Trolling and to get some quick message upvotes (by accident).

Comment: Near a cliff: "Try jumping"

Comment: @Grenyn Two years later the message is still there. At least I think it's the same, the one I think about I found in Iron Keep, first big open area.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: It's a Farce!

Online players know that you cannot access the wall while there is a message there, so they can actually hide the fact that there is no wall, instead causing frustrated players to strafe the wall while mashing the button to no avail.

However: if there is actually a wall there, the only way to access it is to go offline, so that you won't be able to see the messages.

**EDIT** As @Yuki has explained, if you cannot open a wall due to a message being there, it is an attempt to trick you, because there is no illusionary wall there. Instead, if a message is in the way, the wall will be opened first, then the message will be able to be read.

Comment: This is inaccurate as the game prioritizes opening illusory walls over reading messages. Many "illusory wall" messages are in fact lies and bad attempts at trolling.

Comment: @Yuki depending on the platform. PC users have this precedence, whereas console users (currently, or at least as far as I have seen) do not.

Comment: Most discussions I've found on console versions (I play on PC myself) agree that this precedence still occurs.

Comment: Well there you go.